# "Let $G$ be a planar graph. Show that every pair of vertex-disjoint odd cycles in $G^c$ is connected by an edge." Can't figure out why "odd" matters.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, planar-graphs

If $C_1,C_2$ are vertex-disjoint cycles in $G^c$, of lengths $m,n$ respectively, not connected by an edge, then their complement has a $K_{m,n}$ minor with $m,n\geq 3$, so $G$ contains $K_{3,3}$ as a minor and hence cannot be planar. But I must be missing something here since the problem assumes that the $C_1,C_2$ are *odd* cycles; not just any old cycles. What am I missing?

Comment: The complement is not necessarily $K_{m,n}$. There might be edges that goes between the cycle.

Comment: @hbm You're right, I edited it to change slightly. Is what I have now true?

Comment: @crf This is just speculation, but maybe this was intended as a lead-in question, and the oddness of the cycles has some later implication (say, for coloring or for perfect matchings)?

Comment: @ErickWong it seems to be in isolation in this case; can you see anything wrong with the proof above?